# Definition of $a^b$ for $a\in C_p$ and $b\in\mathbb{Z}_p^*$

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

In a paper I found the notion $(1+T)^b\in \mathbb{Q}_p[\![T]\!]$, where $b\in\mathbb{Z}_p^*$. It is implied that this powerseries converges for elements  with norm $<1$.  I am now trying to define $a^b$ for $a\in C_p$, the completion of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, and $a\in \mathbb{Q}_p[\![T]\!]$. I tried this by defining  $b^a:= \exp(b  \log(a))$ but the $p$-adic exponential function is only defined on elements with norm $<p^{-1/(p-1)}$. I would like to define $a^b$ for elements $a\in C_p$  with $|a|<1$. Is this possible and if yes how?

Comment: $(1+f(T))^b \overset{def}= \sum_{k=0}^\infty {b \choose k} f(T)^k \in \mathbb{C}_p[[T]]$ when $b \in \mathbb{C}_p, f(T) \in T\, \mathbb{C}_p[[T]]$. Also it seems you are interested in $p$-adic analytic functions.

Comment: You are right, I am interested where the functions converge. Especially where $(1+T)^b$ converges. How would $\binom{b}{k}$ be defined for $b\notin \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}_p[[T]]$ is a field of formal series, not of (analytic) functions ! You need to look at $|{b \choose k}|_p$. If $b \in \mathbb{N}$ then ${b \choose k} \in \mathbb{Z}$ thus $|{b \choose k}|_p \le 1$, and since it is continuous in $b$, it stays true for $b \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ and the radius of convergence of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty {b \choose k} x^k$ is $x \in \mathbb{C}_p, |x|_p < 1$. For $b \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ I'm not sure.

Comment: IIRC an equivalent way of getting these is the following: 1) pick a sequence $(b_n)$ of integers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=b$ (this is possible because $\Bbb{Z}$ is dense in $\Bbb{Z}_p$). 2) try to prove that the sequence $\bigl((1+T)^{b_n}\bigr)$ converges in $\Bbb{Q}_p[[T]]$.

Comment: I meant $|{i \choose k}|_p = |1/k!|_p$ and hence $(1+x)^i$ has the same radius of convergence as $\exp(x)$. Now $(1+x)^{pb}$ converges for $|x|_p < 1$ if $|b|_p \le 1$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen For $b,x \in \mathbb{C}_p,|b|_p \le 1$ I find $(1+x)^b= \sum_{k=0}^\infty {b \choose k} x^k$ converges for $|x|_p < p^{(a-1) / (p-1)}$ if $p^{-a} = \inf_{n =0 \ldots p-1} |b-n|_p$

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I think I got it now either ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something I know a little about.

(1) If you’re taking about series over a $p$-adic field, $(1+x)^z$ is well defined as a series in $\Bbb Z_p[[x]]$ when $z\in\Bbb Z_p$. Note that the exponent need not be in $\Bbb Z_p^*$. Note also that the coefficients of the series are in $\Bbb Z_p$, not merely in $\Bbb Q_p$. As Jyrki suggested, one way to construct this series is to find a sequence of positive integers $\{n_i\}$ whose limit is the $p$-adic integer $z$, and form the limit of the series (they are actually polynomials!) $(1+x)^{n_i}$, that is
$$
\text{when }\lim_in_i=z\,,\qquad(1+x)^z=\lim_i(1+x)^{n_i}\,.
$$
The limit of series is to be taken *coefficientwise*, not uniformly in $i$.Of course there’s a lot to be proved: that the limit of the polynomials does exist, and that the final result doesn’t depend on the sequence of integers going to $z$. None of this is hard.

(2) Another way of defining $(1+x)^z$ is to use the good old Binomial expansion:
$$
(1+x)^z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom znx^n\,,\quad\text{where }\binom zn=\frac{z(z-1)\cdots(z-n+1)}{n!}\,.
$$
Here, you must note that if $z\in\Bbb Z_p$, the polynomial $\binom zn$ takes values in $\Bbb Z_p$. Why? Because if $z\in\Bbb Z^{\ge0}$, then $\binom zn\in\Bbb Z$, and you use continuity of the polynomial function $\binom zn$.

(3) If you’re worrying about the domain of convergence of the series $(1+x)^z$, where $z\in\Bbb Z_p$, then since the coefficients are all in $\Bbb Z_p$, you have a series convergent for all $x$ with $|x|_p<1$. If $z\notin\Bbb Z^{\ge0}$, then I believe the domain of convergence will be no larger than what I just specified.

(4) If you want to define $(1+a)^b$ for $a\in\Bbb C_p$ and $|a|_p<1$, you may start by taking the logarithm of $1+a$: this is well defined, using the familiar series for $\log(1+x)$. But you must be warned that the range (image) of the log is all of $\Bbb C_p$ (!!) This is easily seen, using the Newton polygon of $\log(1+x)-\zeta$ for your arbitrary given $\Bbb C_p$-number $\zeta$. And of course the logarithm is many-to-one (in fact $\infty$-to-one) in this context, so you’re not going to be able to make a choice of an antilogarithmic value. I don’t think that you’ll get far in defining $(1+a)^b$ when $b$ is not a $p$-adic integer—there’s some formal-group magic going on there.

(5) Returning to the definability of the logarithm, you see that $\log(\xi)$ must be zero for any root of unity $\xi$. You may be disappointed at this, but the fact makes it possible to define the logarithm as $\log:\Bbb C_p^*\to\Bbb C_p$ by the simple expedient of proclaiming that $\log(p)=1$. Arbitrary, yes, but also natural. With this, you define $\log(p^\mu)=\mu$ for any rational number $\mu$; the multivaluedness of $z^\mu$ doesn’t matter ’cause two different valued are related by a root of unity, and these have trivial logarithm. Then every $z\in\Bbb C_p^*$ may be written $z=p^\mu\xi(1+a)$ with $\mu$ rational, $\xi$ a root of unity, and $|a|<1$. for this, you need that the residue field of $\Bbb C_p$ is the union (direct limit) of finite fields. And so the log of $z$ is well defined, as a $\Bbb C_p$-number.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer.